# Scope resolution operator and const

Tags: c++

Let's take the following code:

```
#include <string> // std::string    
using namespace std;
int main() {
  //const::int i = 42;       -> Error: "expected id-expression before 'int'"
  const::string str = "Foo"; // No error: why?
}
```

Why does this code compiles? The error "expected id-expression before XXX" is only present when XXX is a fundamental type.

```
const::char c = 1;   // error: expected id-expression before 'char'
const::double d = 2; // error: expected id-expression before 'double'
const::float f = 3;  // error: expected id-expression before 'float'
const::bool b = 4;   // error: expected id-expression before 'bool'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const::string` is parsed as `const ::string`. `::string` means to look up `string` in the global namespace, and since you have injected `std` into the global namespace, `std::string` is found and everything is dandy.

`int` is a built-in type and isn't in any namespace, so there's no such thing as `::int` or `std::int`, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

`::something` tells the compiler to look for `something` in global namespace, but `int` is keyword (not defined anywhere), while `string` (resp. `std::string`) is class defined in `<string>` so your code is equivalent to this one

```
#include <string> // std::string    
using namespace std;
int main() {
  //const ::int i = 42;       -> Error: "expected id-expression before 'int'"
  const ::string str = "Foo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It compiles because

```
using namespace std;
```

pulls the entire `std` namespace into the global namespace, so `::string` is the same as `std::string`.  Your line in question is actually interpreted as

```
const ::string str = "Foo";
```

However, `int` is a keyword (and a fundamental type), and not a user-defined name that resides in any namespace.  So `::int` doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is not the right answer. `const::std::string str = "Foo";` also compiles.

Comment: Of course it does, but the OP's code uses `::string`, not `::std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `using namespace std;` is bit of a red herring. Note that `const::std::string str = "Foo";` also compiles. The reason this compiles (and the reason your `const::string str = "Foo";` compiles) is because `::` is the scope resolution operator. Spacing is irrelevant. Just as there's no difference between `a+b+c` and `a + b + c`, there's no difference between `const::string str` and `const :: string str` (and similarly, between `const::std::string str` and `const :: std :: string str`).

`::`,`::std::`, and `std::` are all examples of a *nested-name-specifier*, which is described in 5.1.1 ¶8 of c++ n3290 (a draft of the C++11 standard). The `const` is a keyword and this cannot be interpreted as the leading part of a *nested-name-specifier*. This means that `const::string` can only be interpreted as if you had written `const ::string`.

In the context of `using namespace std;` at global namespace level, there's nothing wrong with using `::string` because the leading `::` means to look up what follows in the global namespace. You've pulled all of namespace `std` into the global namespace. Thus `const::string str` declares `str` as a `const`-qualified variable of type `std::string`.

What about `const::int i = 42;`? There's no place in the standard for such a construct. Looking at 7.1.6.2 ¶1 (c++n3290), A *simple-type-specifier* is

- A *type-name*, optionally preceded by a *nested-name-specifier*,
- A *nested-name-specifier* **template** *simple-template-id*,
- One of the built-in primitive types,
- The **auto** keyword, or
- A *decltype-specifier*.

A *type-name* is a *class-name*, an *enum-name*, a *typedef-name*, or a *simple-template-id*. The built-in primitive types do not fall in the category of a *type-name*. This means that the following will (and does) compile:

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

typedef int Int; // Now we can use ::Int because Int is a type-name.

using namespace std;
int main() {
  const::Int i = 42;         // No error.
  const::string str = "Foo"; // No error.
  cout << i << ' ' << str << '\n';
}
```